# Как использовать переменные заданные в другом файле?

Tags: php

Есть определенные переменные, которые везде одинаковые, и которые можно вынести в отдельный файл. Как мне в файле config.php, например, сделать добавить переменные
`$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "login", "pass", "blog");`
и
`define('__DIR_PUBLIC__', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public');`

- еще вопрос по поводу последней строки. Я задаю константу, а юзать ее я должен через
  `echo __DIR_PUBLIC__;`, ведь так???

Comment: По поводу  `define('__DIR_PUBLIC__', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public');'`. Проблема с подключением. Если я подключаю через `include 'phpinit/config.php';`, то в файле просто выводятся занения констант. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php 
require_once ('путь');
?>
```